# Spring data jpa jsp - проблема с русскими буквами

Tags: java, jsp, spring-data-jpa

Программа использует Spring-data-jpa, Tomcat, MySql, из базы скрипт удачно заносит русские буквы в базу, отображается на jsp все хорошо. Но если нужно добавить новые данные со страницы или изменить, появляются всякие крякозябры, как понял это нечто байткодовое. Проблема скорее всего с кодировками в jsp. Там прописано:

```
 <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

На SOF не нашел решения. Конечно буду искать дальше, может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) На странице должна быть строка кодировки, как написано выше:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

2) В web.xml нужно добавить:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[Решение отсюда помогло](https://qa-help.ru/questions/spring-jsp-problema-s-russkimi-bukvami)

3) Добавлять в джава-конфиг ресолвер не обязательно, но можно:

```
resolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Вот собственно и вся проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте url, по которому подключаетесь к базе данных, в параметрах необходимо указать кодировку.
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdname? useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8

Comment: Да, все правильно, это чтобы записи из скрипта добавлялись в базу-данных, иначе тоже будут крякозябры или знаки вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

посмотри ещё в  самой среде разработки  Encoding выберите кодировку UTF-8 .

Comment: Это тоже правильно, первым делом в настройках проекта все нужно установить, чтобы избежать возможных дальнейших проблем.